# How to convert text file that contain colon seperated data into JSON object?

Tags: json, creation

I have a text file that contain colon separated data. How I can convert it into JSON object? I have the following text in a file:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:Campus Police
N:Campus Police
TEL:555-EDU-HELP
ADR:8230 Boone Blvd.;Bldg 001;;Vienna;VA;22181;
X-MS-OL-DEFAULT-POSTAL-ADDRESS:01155
EMAIL:police@wisconsin.edu
REV:20120501T180000Z
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:Campus Medical Clinic
N:Campus Medical Clinic
TEL:555-EDU-HURT
ADR:8230 Boone Blvd.;Bldg 001;;Vienna;VA;22181;
X-MS-OL-DEFAULT-POSTAL-ADDRESS:01155
EMAIL:medical@wisconsin.edu
REV:20120501T180000Z
END:VCARD
```

Comment: You should look for some [parsing tool](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/92/good-tools-to-parse-repetitive-unstructured-data)

Comment: It's a big ask. Though frankly it already looks a lot like json.

Comment: What language/framework or something else you use? Add some concreteness to question.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I have to convert it into JSON object and JSON Array in java only without any third party API. What should I do and How to make JSON array using java only .

Answer (score 1):

Below code is in java. May be you need few changes according to your requirements.

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            readFile();
        }

        public static void readFile() throws IOException {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("d:/input.txt");
                BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
                String line = null;
                String obj = new String("[");
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.split(":").length > 1) {
                        Entry entry = new Entry(line.split(":")[0], line.split(":")[1]);
                        obj = obj +" \n "+ entry.toString();
                    }
                }
                obj = obj.replaceAll("\"BEGIN\":\"VCARD\"", "{");
                obj = obj.replaceAll("\"END\":\"VCARD\"", "},");
                obj = obj.substring(0, obj.lastIndexOf(","));
                obj = obj + "\n]";

                System.out.println(obj);
                br.close();
            } catch ( Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                fileInputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    class Entry {
        private String key;
        private String value;
        Entry (String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\""+ key + "\"" +  ":" +  "\"" +  value + "\"";
        }
    }
```

> output is similar to json format.

```
[ 
 { 
 "VERSION":"2.1" 
 "FN":"Campus Police" 
 "N":"Campus Police" 
 "TEL":"555-EDU-HELP" 
 "ADR":"8230 Boone Blvd.;Bldg 001;;Vienna;VA;22181;" 
 "X-MS-OL-DEFAULT-POSTAL-ADDRESS":"01155" 
 "EMAIL":"police@wisconsin.edu" 
 "REV":"20120501T180000Z" 
 }, 
 { 
 "VERSION":"2.1" 
 "FN":"Campus Medical Clinic" 
 "N":"Campus Medical Clinic" 
 "TEL":"555-EDU-HURT" 
 "ADR":"8230 Boone Blvd.;Bldg 001;;Vienna;VA;22181;" 
 "X-MS-OL-DEFAULT-POSTAL-ADDRESS":"01155" 
 "EMAIL":"medical@wisconsin.edu" 
 "REV":"20120501T180000Z" 
 }
]
```